# ubuntu perl can not get shell output?

Tags: perl, shell

I run command in perl script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
`tar zvcf /tmp/js.tgz -C /home/cuidehe/js .`;
```

I got `/tmp/js.tgz`, but I can not get the verbose output?

Comment: Try with a print before the backticks. You are not printing the output of the command.

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: @el.pescado I use this command in osx, I do not need `print`, I will get the output

Comment: Where would you like output to go?

Answer (score 3):

[``` Backticks(``) or qx ```](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) runs a command and returns the `STDOUT`. So, you just need a variable to capture `STDOUT`. `STDERR` is untouched.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $stdout = `tar zvcf /tmp/js.tgz -C /home/cuidehe/js .`;

print "$stdout";
```

**Or,**

You can use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).It runs a command and returns its exit status(`STDOUT` and `STDERR` are untouched).

```
my $exit_status = system('tar zvcf /tmp/js.tgz -C /home/cuidehe/js .');
print "Exit Status: $exit_status\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a target for the command output within Perl:

```
my $output = `tar zvcf /tmp/js.tgz -C /home/cuidehe/js .`;
print $output;
```

All output lines end up in $output.
Naming the variable $STDOUT isn't good, because it's a reserved keyword in Perl.

The command will likely produce more than one line of output. Using `open` might be better:

```
open my $fh,'-|','tar zvcf /tmp/js.tgz -C /home/cuidehe/js .'
    or die 'Error launching tar';
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp; # Remove the trailing \n from the input line
    print "Got line: $_\n"; # Do whatever you want here.
}
close $fh;
```

You may also capture STDERR using

```
open my $fh,'-|','tar zvcf /tmp/js.tgz -C /home/cuidehe/js . 2>&1'
    or die 'Error launching tar';
```

This will redirect any error to STDERR and you get both (files and errors) to the same `$fh`.

[IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Open3) could capture both (STDOUT and STDERR) to different filehandles.

Update (thanks to @Dummy00001):

```
my @output = `tar zvcf /tmp/js.tgz -C /home/cuidehe/js .`;
```

will return each line of the tar-output as one array item.

Comment: For completeness: `my @output = qx{tar ...};`

Comment: Thanks. Added it to the answer.